# División con decimales en python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
numero = 1075820

resultado = numero / 1000000
print resultado
```

Cuándo lo ejecuto me da 1 en vez de 1.075820, esto no me pasa en python 3, como le puedo hacer para que me de el resultado con decimal.

Answer (score 3):

En Python 2.7 cualquier operacion con enteros, da un entero. Para que te de el resultado con decimales, unos de los dos tiene que ser float.

```
numero = 1075820

resultado = numero / 1000000.0
print resultado #1.07582
```

Comment: En Python 2.7, porque a partir de Python 3.5 las divisiones siempre retornan un flotante

Comment: Si así es. Corrijo la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 funciona de una manera diferente a Python 3 en esta materia, así como en muchas otras. En Python 2 el operador `/` siempre producirá una división entera si ambos operandos son enteros (`int`). Sin embargo, cuando Python 2.2 fue lanzado en 2002, se propuso un cambio en el comportamiento de estas operaciones (incluyendo `//`), que apareció como el comportamiento por defecto en Python 3: el operador `/` siempre producirá un resultado de punto flotante  (`float`), incluso cuando los operandos sean `int`; mientras, se recomendó el uso de `from __future__ import division`, para tener disponible el cambio en Python 2, lo que también es muy útil para portar códigos a Python 3.

```
In [1]: from __future__ import division

In [2]: numero = 1075820

In [3]: resultado = numero / 1000000

In [4]: print resultado
1.07582
```